# Are external updates visible with the Oracle Driver in simple JDBC queries?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I've been trying to understand how an update made from a different session will affect the session held by a runnning program, using JDBC with Oracle Driver (ojdbc6.jar, db version 11.2). I'm confused by the documentation over here, especially table 17-1: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28628

Assuming the following code:

```
String SQL_QUERY = "select duration, cost from sample_table where name = ? and day = ? and type = ?";

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_QUERY);

ps.setString(1,name);
ps.setInt(2,day);
ps.setInt(3,type);

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
    SampleObject so = new SampleObject(); //default constructor
    so.setDuration(rs.getInt(1));
    so.setRate(rs.getDouble(2));
}

rs.close();
//and so on...
```

Suppose I have ran this query several times, for several different parameters, and my program has been running for a couple of hours.

Through a different session (in my case a sqldeveloper connection), I update this table (or delete a row from it) and commit the update.

Right after that, I query the table through the code but I do not see the updated results, I keep seeing the old values. I repeat my test and the results keep coming back with the old values.

I stop the running program, start it again with no changes and after repeating the test, I see the updated values.

What's going on? I haven't set any explicit cache mechanisms, the code to query the database is as simple as it can be. Is there any default caching going on? How can I guarantee I would always see the most updated values, regardless of which session has changed them?

EDIT: One thing that I did not mention at first: when this showed up my first thought was obviouslly "oh, I forgot to commit", then commited again. No changes. Run the test with the code on my local machine, saw the new values. Ran in the server, did not see.

Comment: Is that really the whole code you are showing us? Sounds like you changed the isolation level (e.g. through JDBC or using ALTER SESSION).

Comment: the only piece I haven't shown is acquiring the connection, but the session wasn't changed in any way

Comment: Try explicitely setting the isolation level to READ_COMMITTED (using an ALTER SESSION).

Comment: But isn't READ_COMMITED the default isolation level?

Comment: It is, but your description of the problem indicates that for some reason your program is *not* using that level.

Comment: So what's different between the server and your local computer? (And did you try to set the isolation level?)

Comment: Haven't tried yet, I don't have access to the db right now. My local machine is windows, I'm running the application on eclipse, with JVM 1.6.0_29. The server is redhat, with JVM 1.6.0_26. However, I'm using different drivers, I hadn't noticed that... my local machine has ojdbc14.jar, the server has ojdbc6.jar. Other than that configurations are the same.

Comment: Turns out oracle had nothing to do with this. Just an uninitialized variable that went undetected and wasn't found for a long time. :( If I could, would vote down my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Changes only occur when you COMMIT them. Before you do that, you can't see the changes. Afterward you can see the change.

Comment: Well in the post Vitor writes: "*I update this table .. and commit the update*". So I assume his changes **are** being committed (if not that would also explain the problem).

Comment: In that case there is no reason you shouldn't see the changes, so there is something wrong with your understanding of the situation.

Comment: I assume there is something wrong with my understanding, but I'm sure I have commited the changes. When this showed up my first thought was obviouslly "oh, I forgot to commit", then commited again. No changes. Run the test with the code on my local machine, saw the new values. Ran in the server, did not see.

Comment: @VitorDeMario: the "*locally it's fine, on the server it's not*" is new information. You did not mention this in your initial post. So apparently you are not telling us the whole story.